# beaglebone black wireless bluetooth AVRCP

Tags: bluetooth, beagleboneblack, bluez, avrcp

I am working on a project with the beagle bone black wireless, where I need to be able to send music control commands to a phone. Note, I don't want to stream music to my beaglebone. I have spent about a week looking online, and found very little about this.

The OS for the beaglebone is Debian Jessie. I can get things like hci0tool, Bluetoothctl, hciconfig to work. I can detect and pair to a device. It seems though that my connection only lasts for the pairing process, and fails every time afterwards.

My current process is executing:

```
sudo su
bluetoothctl
power on
agent on
default-agent
scan on
```

I get the mac address

```
scan off
pair <MAC Address>
trust <MAC Address>
connect <MAC Address>
```

As of now pairing and trust succeed, though the connection ends after pairing finishes. And I have no idea of where to start for sending a command to a phone.

Answer (score 0):

Connect call on Device1 interface will tries to connect all the profiles supported between the device and adapter. This happens by negotiating or exchanging the supported profiles.

Connection may not be possible when Adapter doesn't support the minimal requirement of profiles which is needed by the Device. In this case, you may need A2DP provider in adapter end to get connection successful. Yes, this is contradictory to this [statement](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/device-api.txt#n21).

If you don't want to connect with all the profiles between Device and Adapter, then you can use [ConnectProfile](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/device-api.txt#n61) method in Device1 interface.

But bluetoothctl doesn't provide commands to achieve neither ConnectProfile nor you AVRCP commands.

You need to use D-Bus calls to get the communication with Bluetoothd. If your application is command line/shell based, you can use dbus-send/gdbus commands to address the D-Bus interface.

Although bluez-tools implements [media control](https://github.com/khvzak/bluez-tools/blob/master/src/lib/bluez/media_control.c) AVRCP commands, it doesn't provide any utility which uses it. Either you can compile bluez-tools as library and develop application using the media control API or use dbus-send/gdbus.

I have started with some samples using GDBUS, but not yet for AVRCP controls. See here : https://gist.github.com/parthitce
and Documentation here: https://www.linumiz.com/category/blog/